# Suppress Tensorflow "Executing op" messages when using TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I understand that for Tensorflow 2 onwards, the output that is printed by Tensorflow can be suppressed fairly easily according to the level:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```

However, when I use TPU on Google Colab, messages which start with "Executing op" are not filtered out at all using this approach. How do I filter these messages out?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use a custom filter from `logging` which parses `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`:

```py
# Suppress TPU messages which start with "Executing op"

import sys, re, logging

class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr_name)

    def write(self, data):
        if not data.startswith("Executing op"):
            self.stream.write(data)
            self.stream.flush()

    def flush(self):
        self.stream.flush()
  
sys.stdout = Filter(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = Filter(sys.stderr)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I am not too sure if this is elegant but I couldn't find a better solution. Hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same issue.

Comment: After posting this, I realized why I have these messages in the first place. I was trying [Tensorflow's GPU sample code](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#logging_device_placement) out and set `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)`, and doing so enables device placement logging which causes any Tensor allocations or operations to be printed. I removed the line and restarted my notebook and no such message prints now. I am a fool.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake, joining team fool..

remove "tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)"